# How to force Windows 10 Mail app to remove bad account?

Tags: windows-10, email, email-client, windows-mail

I recently migrated my PC from one domain to another. This took some regedit changes...

Now one of the configured email accounts in the Windows 10 Mail and Calendar app is invalid.
The email address is shown in quotes and the account has no functionality (does not receive, send or provide any options).
The mail app does not show any warnings or errors except when I try to send a email. It does not provide any solution in any case.

**I want to remove the email account, but I can't. What can I do?**

Normally the email account could be removed via the account settings within the Mail app but the settings for this bugged email do not open. If I try to open the account setting the app doesn't do anything (for other email accounts it still works).

I did go into the app setting and did a full reset of the Windows 10 Mail app but that did not help.

I did deinstall the app from my PC and reinstalled it but the mail account is still there...

There were 3 accounts configured before. The other two were Exchange accounts and still worked after the migration. By the reset these were successfully removed but the bad account (imap configuration) stayed.

I'm out of ideas. Where are these configurations saved? Can I manually delete the mail configurations where ever they are stored? They seem to survive the deinstall.

Some screenshots for clarity:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may have removed from the Registry some of the information needed to delete the account. It might be easier to start with no accounts, ad add each one, an account at a time.

Comment: Remove Windows 10 Mail and Calendar.  Start, Settings, Apps.  Restart and Install the App from the Store.  See now if you ca remove the Account.

Comment: @John as stated in my question I already reinstalled the app. After the fresh install the email account is already present / still present.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That is what I'm trying to do but I don't know how. I'm unable to remove all accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out where the configuration of the Mail and Calendar app is saved.

It is in the folder: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Comms`

Solution:

1. Log out and into another local admin account (or start Windows in safe mode).
2. Rename the `Comms` folder to `Comms_BAK`
3. Log back in, start the Mail client and all configuration should be gone

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

These apps do not store account information themselves. Instead, they rely on Windows to do so. It is similar (but not quite the same) to the concept Android uses.

Go to Settings → Accounts → Email & accounts:

[image: Email & accounts settings]

You should be able to remove the account from there.

If not, you may have to create a new user profile.

Comment: The email account is not listed under "Email & accounts".

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that the Account Settings doesn’t open for the bugged email , I would suggest that you could run the **troubleshooter**: Select the **Start**  button, and then select **Settings**  > **Update & Security**   > **Troubleshoot**, and then from the list select **Windows Store apps**  > **Run the troubleshooter**.

You may also want to try the steps mentioned below and see if that helps:

1. Press **Windows logo key + I**, to open **Settings**.
2. Click on **Accounts**, and select Access work or school from the left pane.
3. Now, click on the email account and select **Remove**.

Find [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security-winpc/i-cannot-delete-email-account-mail-app-windows-10/720e893b-5e2b-4c6b-a565-7c61e63a0480), it mentioned that you can logon to your computer using a different account (maybe local admin account) instead of the domain alias. If you have no, you can create a new local account. Then you will be able to open the account settings to delete the bugged email account.

You can have a try to see if it helps for you.

Comment: The troubleshooting did only suggest to reset apps if I have problems (it did not detect anything). The reset I already did and can be repeated without the email account being removed from the mail app. The mail account does not show up in the global account settings.

Comment: I have modified the answer and provided another solution, please have a try.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. I went with the initial solution I hoped for: Removing the folder where the configuration is saved to. See my own answer to this.