# Remove e-mail address from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, privacy

Recently, I found that one of my e-mail addresses somehow made its way too little too far into the system, even into the settings(*):

[image]

My account is local, and I've never used any e-mail client on this computer, however, I use Skype and occasionally check that e-mail through a browser, I assume Windows 10 spied it out of one of those. I have tried removing that e-mail address from the system, but to no avail. Where is it stored and how do I get rid of it?

What have I tried so far.
The usual advice that comes from googling is to change your account type from "Microsoft account" to "local account", and then remove the e-mail from the "Email & accounts" settings. However, my account was "local" to begin with, and for some reason the "Remove" button is absent (I checked a friend's computer, and it was there, but not on mine):

[image]

I have uninstalled all I could that was possibly related to Microsoft identification (Mail, XBox-related stuff, etc.)

I have searched for the e-mail with regedit and removed every instance of it (probably not a very wise move, but whatever).

I have tried loggin into Microsoft site with that hotmail account and remove all devices.

I have tried what's described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1588277/how-to-force-windows-10-mail-app-to-remove-bad-account) (removing the C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Comms folder).

None of the above had any effect. Is there a way to remove it? I have accepted the fact that in our brave new world I can't really have that kind of privacy, but at least I'd like to remain oblivious to that.

*(*) the name, face picture and e-mail address are not real*

Comment: As you can see by your screenshot it is a Microsoft account. Did you check what options you get my clicking manage? Did you try to create a local account and to remove the other account? This will remove other settings as well but should be an option.

Comment: @Headcrab - You made no mention that never linked your Microsoft Account to your local account.  You should [edit] your question to include that vital information

Answer (score 1):

> My account is local, and I've never used any e-mail client on this computer, however, I use Skype and occasionally check that e-mail through a browser, I assume Windows 10 spied it out of one of those. I have tried removing that e-mail address from the system but to no avail. Where is it stored and how do I get rid of it?
> [image]

You can remove the device from your Microsoft Account [here](https://account.microsoft.com/devices?fref=home.drawers.devices.manage-devices&refd=account.microsoft.com).  This will log you out of your Microsoft Account from Windows Store, Skype, and other Microsoft Account associated applications.

> What have I tried so far. The usual advice that comes from googling is to change your account type from "Microsoft account" to "local account", and then remove the e-mail from the "Email & accounts" settings. However, my account was "local" to begin with, and for some reason, the "Remove" button is absent (I checked a friend's computer, and it was there, but not on mine):
> [image]

You are looking in the incorrect location.  On supported versions of Windows 10, the "Sign in with a local account" option is located within "Your Info" within Settings -> Accounts

[image]

> None of the above had any effect. Is there a way to remove it? I have accepted the fact that in our brave new world I can't really have that kind of privacy, but at least I'd like to remain oblivious to that.

The only way to unlink your Microsoft Account is with the "Sign in with a local account" or create a new local account.

> I do not log in with that e-mail and its password - I log in with a simple username and a local password. If I open Settings -> Accounts -> Your info, it shows me that local account information and tells me how it would be better if I use a Microsoft account, and gives a link "Sign in with a Microsoft account instead". Maybe it sniffed my Microsoft account and associated it with the local one - then how do I dissociate them back?

This means your local account is NOT linked to a Microsoft Account.  You can disassociate your Microsoft Account with your device by clicking the link [here](https://account.microsoft.com/devices?fref=home.drawers.devices.manage-devices&refd=account.microsoft.com) and removing the device.

Comment: I have tried removing the device from Microsoft account, it didn't help. My account is local, if I go to Settings -> Accounts -> Your Info, it says "USERNAME, Local Account, Administrator, yada yada, Sign in with a Microsoft account instead". I _think_ I never linked it to a Microsoft account, I don't remember ever doing so, but I can't definitely 100% pinky swear, it's been a while since I set this PC up - but even if I did, looks like there's a way to undo that, only for some reason it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Once you removed the device you logged out of your local account?

Comment: I restarted the whole damn thing after each of those steps, to make sure.

Comment: @Headcrab - Are you logged into your Microsoft Account within OneDrive and/or Microsoft Store by chance?

Comment: OneDrive is uninstalled. Microsoft Store was indeed logged into that microsoft account - I logged out, rebooted, nothing changed - the e-mail is there, no option to remove.